# Retraining Inception5h model from TensorFlow Android Camera Demo

Tags: android, python, tensorflow

[TensorFlow Android Camera Demo](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/android/) uses [Inception5h model](https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/models/inception5h.zip) for live image recognition which delivers exceptional performance. Since I haven't had success retraining Inception5h I've gone with [InceptionV3 model](http://download.tensorflow.org/models/image/imagenet/inception-2015-12-05.tgz) but it's not quite as snappy at image recognition. So I'm back at the beginning trying to retrain (or transfer learn) Inception5h model. I've tried modifying [retrain.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py) but it's clearly written just for the v3 model. 5h model doesn't contain "pool_3/_reshape:0", "DecodeJpeg/contents:0" or "ResizeBilinear:0" tensors to begin with. There are other differences as well.

I'm a bit of a newbie at machine learning and TensorFlow so I'd greatly appreciate clear steps as to what I have to do.

Thank you!

Comment: The inception5h model found at download.tensorflow.org is already stripped  of unused nodes for mobile inference, which is why it's not finding the DecodeJpeg and ResizeBilinear  nodes. You can try adding them back in for retraining (you should be able to use the Inceptionv3 GraphDef as a reference), or just convert your image data yourself into RGB format at size 224x224 as a preprocessing step.

Comment: @AndrewHarp, Would it be good idea to retrain on full inception5H model and later run optimize_for_inference.py on the model for Android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the [`retrain.py`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py) script and [tutorial](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/docs_src/tutorials/image_retraining.md) was just updated to work with the [mobilenet](https://research.googleblog.com/2017/06/mobilenets-open-source-models-for.html) architecture.

So that solves the first part of your problem, it's not actually inception5h, but it runs well on mobile with much better accuracy than inception5h.

To actually get it to run in the android example you'll still need to update [these settings](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/tensorflow-for-poets-2/blob/master/android/src/org/tensorflow/demo/ClassifierActivity.java#L61).

I think you should be able to just copy [the settings determined for the mobilenet you choose, from the retrain script](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py#L925) and you might be okay.

---

If you wanted to use a different network, that didn't have the settings in `retrain.py` then the easiest way I can think of to determine them would be to explore the graph with TensorBoard.

So if you **really** wanted to use inception 5h, you could download and unzip it:

```
curl -O https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/models/inception5h.zip
unzip -d inception5h inception5h.zip
```

Then grab this simple script, from the [Tensorflow for Poets: 2 codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets-2/#0) [repo](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/tensorflow-for-poets-2/), to convert the graph `.pb` file to something tensorboard can use:

```
curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/googlecodelabs/tensorflow-for-poets-2/master/scripts/graph_pb2tb.py
```

And run it on your graph.pb:

```
mkdir tb_graph
python graph_pb2tb.py tb/inception5h inception5h/tensorflow_inception_graph.pb
```

And [open it in tensorboard](http://0.0.0.0:6006#graphs):

```
tensorboard --logdir tb_graph
```

Then it might be relatively simple to poke around in the graph and find the names of the nodes you need to fill up your own [`model_info`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py#L925) dict.

I think this is the node you'd want to set as your `bottleneck_tensor`:

[image: TensorBoard screenshot of inception 5h with avgpool0/reshape highlighted]

Answer (score 1):

At the end of retrain.py script you can notice these lines:

```
output_graph_def = graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants(
  sess, graph.as_graph_def(), [FLAGS.final_tensor_name])
with gfile.FastGFile(FLAGS.output_graph, 'wb') as f:
   f.write(output_graph_def.SerializeToString())
```

Here all the variables are saved as constants in a protocol buffer (pb) file which is binary ('wb'). You should also save in a text file the names of the model's classes. Then as the android documentation mentions, you should save these 2 files in a folder named "assets" in the android path of tensorflow. Then there are some modifications that should be done to load the inception-v3 model which you can see here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1269
I hope this will help!

Comment: Thank you for your response but that's not what I'm trying to solve. I already know how to load my model in the Android app. What I'm trying to do is to retrain the Inception5h model, which is a much slimmer Inception model and works much faster on mobile devices.

Comment: Oh ok. I have worked on inception-v3 so I can't help you. Good luck with your research!